# Tcsh loop while the script returns a specific status

Tags: linux, tcsh

I'm new to Tcsh. I'm trying to write a basic script which runs some other script which returns a status. If it returns 0 then it passed, otherwise it failed. I would like to create a loop which runs the script until it passed and goes to sleep for 30 seconds between every try. I run the script like `./script.pl` and I check the status with `$?`, although I'm not sure it's the right status. The passudo code I though of using is:

```
set status=`./script.pl`
while($status != 0)
    sleep 30
    set status=`./script.pl`
end
```

But I'm not sure it's the right approach.

Comment: You're not checking the *status* of `./script.pl`, but its *output*. For running a loop until the *status* of `./script.pl` is 0, use this: `while(1) // ./script.pl && break // sleep 30 // end` (the `//` stay for newlines, because this retarded interface won't let me enter newlines in comments).

Comment: btw, the backtick syntax (`\`...\``) will get you the output of a program (ie what it has written to stdout), not its exit status in all the shells and scripting languages which include it.

Comment: @mosvy : nice that people are still using tcsh. It's very handy, but underappreciated in the corporate arena ;-) . Good luck to all.